# Date format in http request

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, http, wcf-data-services

I have to use this URL:

**http://localhost/Service/DataService.svc/GetTotalPageForRequestFilter?login=ADM&maxDate=''&statut=1&pageSize=10**

But when I use this format I get the error **Bad Request - Error in query syntax.**

I think, it's my date format which is wrong. What is the format to use in to submit a date to my web service?

*maxDate=''*, it's because maxDate can be null

Here is the signature of my method:

```
[WebGet]
public int GetTotalPageForRequestFilter(string login, DateTime? maxDate, short? statut, int pageSize)
{
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: To not specify the date try removing it from the query string.

Comment: Same error without this params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `&maxDate=''` just don't put any value there. `&maxDate=`. As for the error, we need more information to help. Could you post the code that's causing the error?

**EDIT:**
Escape the `login` parameter with `''` and that should work.

Comment: No more code... I'm just entering this URL in my webbrowser to access to the method GetTotalPageForRequestFilter. It's the same error without value in maxData :(

Comment: But did you write the Method? Or have access to it?

Comment: Just an idea, have you tried escaping the `login` parameter with `''`?

Comment: Ahah, Yes Kyle, it's works... it's the login parameter who was in error :). Can you write the answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't include the `maxDate` parameter if it will be null:

```
http://localhost/Service/DataService.svc/GetTotalPageForRequestFilter?login=ADM&statut=1&pageSize=10
```